# Submit Multiple Objects of the Same Model from a Single Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to submit multiple objects (an array of hashes) of the same model from a single form. My params only show one object, even if I try to submit more than one.

My params look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"adjbzaCNxfw==", "serialized_products"=>{"product_id"=>"2", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>"1234567890"}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

I'm expecting a key in the params hash called `serialized_products` with an array of serialized products like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bbT3qiNZxFrO9RYLL3g==", "serialized_products"=>[{"product_id"=>"1", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>"2345454353454"}, {"product_id"=>"1", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>""}, {"product_id"=>"1", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>""}, {"product_id"=>"2", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>"454356536556"}, {"product_id"=>"2", "location_id"=>"1", "serial"=>""}], "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

I get this error when submitting the form:

`undefined method 'permit' for "product_id":String Did you mean? print`

It was working fine before upgrading to Rails 5, from Rails 4.2.

I have the following code, adapted from here:

http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/

Form:

```
<%= form_tag serialized_products_path do %>
  <% @serialized_products.each do |product| %>
    <%= fields_for 'serialized_products[]', product do |p| %>

        <%= p.label :product_id %><br>
        <%= p.text_field :product_id %>

        <%= p.label :location_id %><br>
        <%= p.text_field :location_id %>

        <%= p.label :serial %><br>
        <%= p.text_field :serial %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

SerializedProducts Controller:

```
class SerializedProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_serialized_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    if session[:reference] == nil or session[:location_id] == nil or session[:line_item_ids] == nil
      print "\n\nSession is nil.\n\n"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end

    @reference = session[:reference]
    location_id = session[:location_id]
    @line_items = InventoryAdjustmentItem.where(id: session[:line_item_ids])
    @serialized_products = []
    @line_items.each do |line_item|
      (line_item.quantity).times do 
        @serialized_products.push(SerializedProduct.new(product_id: line_item.product_id, location_id: location_id))
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    params["serialized_products"].each do |serialized_product|
      if serialized_product["serial"].present?
        SerializedProduct.create(serialized_product_params(serialized_product))
      end
    end
    redirect_to :root, notice: 'Serialized product was successfully created.'
    session[:reference] = nil
    session[:location_id] = nil
    session[:line_item_ids] = nil
  end

  private
    def set_serialized_product
      @serialized_product = SerializedProduct.find(params[:id])
    end

    def serialized_product_params(my_params)
      my_params.permit(:product_id, :location_id, :serial)
    end
end
```

Comment: I will look into this its not what I originally thought

Comment: Use `accepts_nested_attributes` and `fields_for` an an association.

Comment: @max Which association? It's the same model.

Comment: can you paste the value of `params["serialized_products"]`